# How can show datepicker calendar in a row which are added newly

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I am trying to show a datepicker calendar in each row of table . But it  shows only first row. When I add new row in a table, the  datepicker is not showed  newly added rows.

Model class

```
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 public string FromDate { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Date only")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public string ToDate { get; set; }
```

Html file

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToDate, new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
 </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="btnUpdate" name="submitButton" value="DeleteAtt"
class="btn btn-primary form-control" onclick="AddNew();">
 <i class="fa fa-save"></i><span class="padding-left-ten">Add New Row</span>
 </button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#FromDate").datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', todayHighlight: true, date: new Date(), autoclose: true, todayBtn: 'linked' });
        $("#ToDate").datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', todayHighlight: true, date: new Date(), autoclose: true, todayBtn: 'linked' });
});
  function AddNew() {
        var clone = $("#tblEntry tr:last").clone().find('input').val('').end().insertAfter("#tblEntry tr:last");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where/how are you adding elements to the page?  What is the resulting client-side markup before and after?

Comment: I was editing the script, Please can you check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First*, you'll need to stop duplicating `id` values in your HTML.  Those need to be unique across the DOM, otherwise your selectors will have no way to identify multiple elements with the same `id`.  Instead, assign a `class` that you can recognize for the date inputs.  For example:

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control date-input" })</td>
```

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToDate, new { @class = "form-control date-input" })

Note the new "date-input" class values.  Then use those to initialize the datepicker plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".date-input").datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', todayHighlight: true, date: new Date(), autoclose: true, todayBtn: 'linked' });
});
```

*Second*, it's important to understand that this will only initialize the datepicker plugin for elements which exist *when this code executes*, which is only once when the page loads.  Any elements added afterward would also need to have the plugin initialized at that time.  So you'd do that in your `AddNew` function:

```
function AddNew() {
    var clone = $("#tblEntry tr:last").clone().find('input').val('').end().insertAfter("#tblEntry tr:last");
    $(clone).find(".date-input").datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', todayHighlight: true, date: new Date(), autoclose: true, todayBtn: 'linked' });
}
```

---

If you like, you can reduce the repeated use of the datepicker plugin configuration by extracting that into its own function.  Perhaps something like this:

```
function initDatepicker(selection) {
    selection.datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', todayHighlight: true, date: new Date(), autoclose: true, todayBtn: 'linked' });
}
```

Then you'd call it in both places with your selected jQuery results:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initDatepicker($(".date-input"));
});
```

and:

```
function AddNew() {
    var clone = $("#tblEntry tr:last").clone().find('input').val('').end().insertAfter("#tblEntry tr:last");
    initDatepicker($(clone).find(".date-input"));
}
```